# pgAdmin 4/v1 keyboard shortcuts

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I have installed brand new pgAdmin 4 (v1.1). I was pretty excited about new tool (version 3 was missing some key features). After few seconds of using version 4 I have realized I cant use shortcuts in Browser window - like `F5` refresh, `DELETE` to remove table/view etc..

In pgAdmin 4 I have found a [Keyboard Shortcuts](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs4/1.x/keyboard_shortcuts.html?highlight=shortcut) which can confirm my fears.

Am I missing something or they removed those shortcuts? Can I map them somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now that's not possible but you can expect those features in future releases of pgAdmin4 once you request for the feature to pgAdmin4 developers on **pgadmin-support(at)postgresql(dot)org** .

Answer (score 1):

I installed 9.6 and pgadmin 4.  After many issues and problems I uninstalled 9.6 and went back to 9.5 and pgadmin 3 it works!